# How to enable Copy, PDF, Excel buttons in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I'd like to enable the Copy, PDF, Excel button, so that it looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code I have which failed to put it up:

```js
var dataSet = [
  ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
  ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
  ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
  ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
  ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
  ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
  ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
  ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
  ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
  ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
  ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
  ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
  ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
  ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
  ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
  ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
  ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
  ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
  ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
  ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
  ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
  ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
  ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
  ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
  ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf'],
    columns: [{
      title: "Name"
    }, {
      title: "Position"
    }, {
      title: "Office"
    }, {
      title: "Extn."
    }, {
      title: "Start date"
    }, {
      title: "Salary"
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
```

Previously we can use [TableTools but now it's called Button](https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/).

In this code you can find the full running code.
Not that in that code I already [included](https://www.datatables.net/download/) the CSS and JS for the "Button"
function. 
What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DataTables Buttons extension](https://www.datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) is not provided by default. So be sure to add it to your dependencies (see the link for more informations). Export buttons such as "Excel", "PDF" require "Flash export" or "HTML5 export" code  or both in [Download builder](https://datatables.net/download/index).

And you have to tell DataTables where to insert the buttons. You have two choices:

- Include character `B` in [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option, for example `dom: 'Bfrtip'`
- Use `$('#example').DataTable().buttons()` to obtains a jQuery collections containing the buttons and insert it where you want.

**DEMO**

```js
var dataSet = [
  ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
  ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
  ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
  ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
  ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
  ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
  ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
  ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
  ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
  ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
  ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
  ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
  ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
  ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
  ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
  ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
  ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
  ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
  ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
  ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
  ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
  ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
  ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
  ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
  ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
  ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
  ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
  ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
  ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
  ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
  ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
  ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
  ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
  ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
  ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
  ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    data: dataSet,
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf'],
    columns: [{
      title: "Name"
    }, {
      title: "Position"
    }, {
      title: "Office"
    }, {
      title: "Extn."
    }, {
      title: "Start date"
    }, {
      title: "Salary"
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jqc-1.11.3,jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/dt/jqc-1.11.3,jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.9,b-1.0.3,b-flash-1.0.3,b-html5-1.0.3/datatables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
```